# Jquery Reimplementation

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey would love to have a take from a more experienced coder about this.

Would appreciate if you could give it to me in the below code format, thanks a lot

Comment: There is `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Comment: `Array.from( document.querySelectorAll("your-selector") )`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

This returns a Node List, to convert that to an Array, you could do

```
const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(".my-selector")];
```

Answer (score 0):

That's called Vanilla Javascript

An example

```js
var myArray = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass')
```

`myArray` will be a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)